# Usage of the word "reinvigorated"

Tags: word-usage

If someone is tired, then they slept for a while. After waking up, can I say to them: I hope you are "reinvigorated"? 
The meaning, I hope they restored their energy from last night example. If not, what is the perfect usage of the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about gaining energy through rest, I think [*refreshed*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/refreshed?s=t) is best. *Reinvigorated* means the same thing, but I don't think it's as commonly used.